# Can a phrase refer to two things (Sense and Reference)?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, frege

I was reading about Frege's sense and reference, and I have a question about it, for example let's say we have 'Charles is the king of England'.

One one hand, 'the king of England' denotes Charles in any sentence, yet you could argue that 'the king of England' itself denotes the idea of being the (male) head monarch of a paticular country, a role that one can occupy.

I understand that Frege differed these two things by 'sense' but with the same reference, however the phrase seems to equally refers to it's 'sense' and its 'reference', one one hand it denotes a person, but also seems to denote *the concept* of that person's status.

Comment: Regarding [Frege’s Theory of Sense and Denotation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#FreLan) we have to note that Frege's theory was motivated by some puzzles regarding names and descriptions. 1/2

Comment: "To explain these puzzles, Frege suggested that in addition to having a denotation, names and descriptions also express a sense.[5] The sense of an expression accounts for its cognitive significance—it is the way by which one conceives of the denotation of the term. The descriptions ‘the morning star’ and ‘the evening star’ denote the same planet, namely Venus, but express different ways of conceiving of Venus and so have different senses. " 2/2

Comment: According to Frege 'the king of England' denotes an individual while 'king of England'  denotes the idea (the concept) of being a king of England. A concept may have more than one "instances": moon of Mars ve moon of Earth.

Comment: Having said that, for F *reference* ( bedeutung) is unique: the individual for a name and the truth value for a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a phrase can have more than one meaning. I would suggest that it is rare for a phrase or word to have only one meaning. In the example you site, the phrase King of Englands can refer to the role of the Kings of England the current occupant of that role or, in certain contexts, any of the previous occupants.